# "To reschedule a date" vs "To set up a date" vs "To line up a date"

Tags: word-usage

Which is the **least formal** and more **common** way to say that you will plan a date (*Romantic encounter*) with someone again?

**Ex 1:**

> Suzy and I didn't get a chance to go on a date this weekend because of her job. We'll **reschedule** our **date** for next weekend.

(*I think this sounds a bit too formal, I don't hear people saying "I have to schedule/reschedule a date with this girl I've been talking to" it sounds to me that the word **schedule/reschedule** is only used for more important situations such a visit to the doctor or a school meeting.*)

**Ex 2:**

> Suzy and I didn't get a chance to go on a date this weekend because of
>   her job. I'll have to **line up** another **date** for next weekend.

*(**Line up** might be the most common way of saying this as I've heard many native speakers using this expression before.)*

**Ex 3:**

> Suzy and I didn't get a chance to go on a date this weekend because of
>   her job. I'll have **to set up** another date for next weekend.

*(This is a little tricky, I've never heard **Let's set up a date** unless it were an unspecified date for something completely different than a **romantic encounter**. For example: **Let's set up a date to play soccer at your house** or **Let me set up an appointment with the doctor**")*

Also I would like to ask whether any of these could be used for **any situation**. Not only a date, but for other stuff such as planning a day so you can go out with friends or planning a date to go to someone's house.

Comment: "Reschedule" only works when you have already arranged for a date. You can't reschedule what you haven't scheduled yet. So you can eliminate that one as a means of arranging an initial date. Schedule sounds really formal for a date. It makes it sound as if someone is arranging a dental appointment.

Comment: ***Arrange*** a date works fine for both business and romantic / social meetings.

Comment: @Don B. Which is the least formal and more common way to say that you will plan a date (Romantic encounter) with someone **again**? This was the title of my question. I think you might've missed it. Are you saying that the word **schedule** doesn't work? but the word **reschedule** does, if you had previously arranged a date.

Comment: Sorry for not reading carefully enough. I meant "reschedule" only works when you  already had a date and then had to cancel it or chose to cancel it.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this: "Let's ***make plans*** to go to the movies this Saturday"?

"we've ***made plans*** to go to the race Saturday."

"We're ***making plans*** to go to the opera tonight."

I think make plans is informal but versatile enough to cover a wide range of situations.

As far as what is least formal, I don't think I could say.  I know if you're talking about going to a movie, you could say, "Let's catch a movie together." That's very informal, but it is relatively limited in what events you can apply it to.